# Cart Rule Configurable product

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, sales

we have some products which are a "Configurable Product" with SImple Products.

Here you can see:

[image]

I created a shopping cart rule "Take 5 get 1". Every option has its own sku. I added all the sku´s to the rule. When i put 6 form the same "Geschmack", it works. But when i put 4 of "Geschmack: Vanille" and 2 of "Geschmack: Schoko" the rule is not working. Why? Can´t Magento work with Configurable Products and different options??

Andre

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Buy X get Y" rule for different X and Y in the Magento default package. The rule we have can only discount some qty of the exactly SAME products.  Like if we get 10 t-shirts we can receive 11-th for free.  But there is NO WAY to receive a belt instead of the t-shirt or a t-shirt of a different color.

The options are either create a custom module or select some ready to use from the Magento Connect.

If you want to create your own, here some tips based on Amasty's "Special Promotions" plugin:

1. Add a new field to be able to set "X" condition
2. Listen for `salesrule_validator_process` event and check if the current item is X
3. If it is X then loop through  $address->getAllItems() and find Y, set discount to Y

Comment: I love how you answered this. A little bit ad (which is totally ok if you ask me) and a proper answer. This is content driven advertisement as I like - and no link <3